# Unable to find .META table

Tags: hbase

I'm new to hbase and I'm trying to understand how the -ROOT- and .META tables look like in the hbase cluster that is being used. I'm not able to locate the .META table.

hbase version : 0.94

1) I first located the -ROOT- node from zknode : get /hbase/root-region-server

2) From the root region server I ran scan '-ROOT-' from hbase shell. I got the following output: 
column=info:server, timestamp=1504089261724, value=hbasedatanode-20:60020

## 3) I logged into hbasedatanode-20 and when I run scan '.META' (from hbase shell) it says table not found

Is there anything I'm missing here? Is it possible that the .META table is not available for scan due to any security setting?

Thanks.

Comment: Apologizing for the bold lettering, I dont know how that happened !

Comment: I hope you were scanning for '.META.'